# UIPath - Get Text by position

Tags: web-scraping, html-table, rpa, uipath

## Is there any way to get the text or UIElement from a position?

I have a table on a website that I need to fetch a cell from.

The HTML table has a column of IDs and a column of status.
I am finding the ID that matches my known ID value and storing the Y part of the position.
This is how I know what row I am on.
Then I go to the status column with a known X coordinate.

What is the best function for me to get the Text/UIElement at those coordinates?

example (I need the status of the object with an ID of '2'):

(should return "bad")

```
 ID | etc | etc | Status | etc
----|-----|-----|--------|-----
 0  | ... | ... |  good  | ...
----|-----|-----|--------|-----
 1  | ... | ... |  great | ...
----|-----|-----|--------|-----
 2  | ... | ... |  bad   | ...
----|-----|-----|--------|-----
 3  | ... | ... |  good  | ...
```

I know you can mouse click on a position, but how can I get the text(UIElement works too) of a position?

*If there is a faster/more reliable method to get the status that doesn't involve coordinates, I'm all ears*

Comment: Can you show the page?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you need. Why you want the bad? Or is it the cell of row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to use UiPath's data scraping feature.

When used on an HTML Table it will return you a data table containing all of the data contained within the table.

You can then use a for each row activity that will loop through the table.

Inside the for each row activity, you can put an If statement with the following condition `row("ID").ToString.Equals("THE ID YOUR LOOKING FOR, IN THIS CASE, 2")`

In the true section of the If statement, you can have an assign activity to get the value of the status column which can be retrieved using the following `row("Status").ToString`. You can leave the false section empty as this won't be needed